# how to change the work directory in java?

Tags: java

This is my project structure. I want to get the data folder's absolute path(/Users/user/IdeaProjects/project/data/post/sourceData) by using relative path, but the test I'm running is inside service folder, so the  absolutePath is always shows "/Users/user/IdeaProjects/project/service/data/post/sourceData".

```
project
  -data
   -post
    -sourceData
  -service
   -test
```

```
String relativePath = "data/post/sourceData";
Path absolutePath = Paths.get(relativePath).toAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(absolutePath);
```

I tried to set the working directory manually, but after I run the code it still print the error result, how can I fix this?

```
String newWorkingDirectory = "/Users/user/IdeaProjects/project/";
System.setProperty("user.dir", newWorkingDirectory);
String relativePath = "data/post/sourceData";
Path absolutePath = Paths.get(relativePath).toAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(absolutePath);  // Outputs
```

Comment: You shouldn't be concerning yourself with the projects directory tree at all. The only thing that's important is the tree of the deployed application. What is your goal actually?

Comment: Hi @g00se because the data folder doesn't exist  if I don't  run the project, so I want to put relative path as constant, and create a function to get absolute path by using relative path, so anyone else can use it when running the project

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how deployed applications work. They are normally deployed as jar files and you have no means of knowing where that will end up. You should be using a directory off the user's home directory as your data repository if you need to write to it. If you don't they should be resources in a folder inside your jar

Comment: Why can't you do `..` to get the parent directory and then convert to an absolute path?

Comment: No that won't cut it. All that will do is tell you what the directory above the current directory is. That's not necessarily the same thing that is desired. It might not even be writable